# QuickTime can't play mp4 generated by ffmpeg without converting first

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, quicktime, matroska

I've created a .mkv file from a DVD using [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) that I've then converted to .mp4 using ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i title00.mkv -c copy -c:s copy output.mp4`

Now when I try opening the .mp4 file using QuickTime, QuickTime first needs to convert it before playing. How do I avoid this? Is the dvd_subtitle the problem? If yes, can I convert this to another subtitle format?

Output from `ffmpeg -i output.mp4`

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:22:32.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5875 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 73.774000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 73.774000, end 395.161000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 395.161000, end 690.857000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 690.857000, end 1010.943000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1010.943000, end 1352.352000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 05
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 5671 kb/s, 24.59 fps, 59.94 tbr, 16k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3 (ac-3 / 0x332D6361), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Side data:
      audio service type: main
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 720x480, 6 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

The MP4 contains MPEG-2 video and AC-3 audio which is unusual and Quicktime may be complaining.

First try is to rename the output to `.m4v`

Else, transcode the MKV to MP4

```
ffmpeg -i title00.mkv -c:s copy output.mp4
```